# Getting the Lead Id from a Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, lead-conversion

I have the following Visualforce page:

```
    <apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="myExtension" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:form >
<apex:commandLink action="{!URLFOR($Action.Lead.Convert, lead.id, [retURL=$CurrentPage.parameters.retURL, nooppti=1], true)}" value="Convert" target="_parent"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I need to write an Apex controller extension which sets a value (checkbox) before converting the lead. 
So I have now created a controller extension "myExtension".
The checkbox on the lead object is called:
`lead_ok__c` and it must be set to true, before converting the lead.

This is my controller so far:

```
        public class myExtension{
            public Lead currentLead {get;set;}

            public myExtension() {
            }

            public PageReference setCheckbox(){
                currentLead = [SELECT Id, lead_ok__c FROM Lead WHERE
                                       Id =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

                //then I need to set the checkbox to true: 
                lead_ok__c = true;

                //then I need to update the record on Salesforce
                update lead with lead_ok__c where Id = CurrentLeadIdFromVFPage;
            }

            //then I need to invoke the lead convert action, ie 
            <apex:commandLink action="{!URLFOR($Action.Lead.Convert, lead.id, [retURL=$CurrentPage.parameters.retURL, nooppti=1], true)}" value="Convert" target="_parent"/>

         }
```

Tia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller pattern to use here is a [controller extension](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_extension.htm) that has a constructor that takes an instance of the standard controller. There is also an [Apex API for converting leads](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_convertLead.htm). Combining the two:

```
public with sharing class myExtension {

    private ApexPages.StandardController sc;

    public myExtension(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        this.sc = sc;
    }

    public PageReference convert() {

        update new Lead(Id = sc.getId(), lead_ok__c = true);

        Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(sc.getId());

        LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus
                WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
        lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
        if (lcr.isSuccess()) {
            return new PageReference('/' + lcr.getContactId());
        } else {
            for (Database.Error e : lcr.getErrors()) {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,
                        e.getMessage()));
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And the Visualforce would change to:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!convert}" value="Convert"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Keith C. I am trying this now. So, on my Apex Page, instead of having that long URL action, I assume I will just write `{!convert}`, right?
I now get a compile error for the invalid type in the line where it says: `for (Error e : lcr.getErrors()) {` Tia.

Comment: @Lily There were a couple of mistakes in the code - try the current version. and see the comment about the Visualforce too.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much. This works very well now!!